# JavaFx: show DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, datepicker, javafx-8

I have a `ComboBox<MyItem>` and I want to show a `DatePicker` when I select a special item from the `ComboBox`. I created a class that extends ComboBox, and I have a DatePicker in that class. I have added a listener to its `selectedItemProperty`:

```
public class CustomComboBox extends ComboBox<MyItem>{

    private DatePicker datePicker;

    public CustomComboBox(){
        getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (MyItem.DATE.equals(newValue)) {
                    initDatePicker();
                    datePicker.show();
                    datePicker.requestFocus();
                }
        });
    }

    private void initDatePicker() {
        if (datePicker == null) {
            datePicker = new DatePicker();
            datePicker.setFocusTraversable(false);
        }
    }
}
```

So if I select the `DATE` item the DatePicker should pop up and If I select a date I want to add as the value of the `ComboBox`
First of all why the datePicker not pops up? The second question is this posible to add the selected date to comboBox as value.

Comment: Please show some more code. Where did you place the code you have shown. We need some context.

Comment: I have edited my code, so you can see the whole class.

Comment: You never put the date picker in the scene graph anywhere. You need to add it to some parent (that is displayed somewhere) for it to be part of the UI. The `show()` method merely shows its popup, but I think it has to be actually visible for this to do anything.

Comment: Ah okay, then do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: No: I don't know what you are trying to do. Specifically, *where* do you want the date picker to appear?

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: Where should the date be added? I guess it's unlikely that it's assignable to `MyItem` and you probably need to use a `ComboBox<Object>` to use both `MyItem` and `LocalDate` as items...

Comment: I have a few items related to Date and Time in that `ComboBox` and when I select the `DATE` item, I want to pop up a datepicker so I can select a date and after selection, to _replace_ somehow the `DATE` item with the chosen date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need something like this:
[image]

I did it by using a popup class from [ControlsFX library](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#popover).

Play with this demo app to understand the main idea.

```
import org.controlsfx.control.PopOver;
// here all other needed dependencies

public class Main extends Application {
    private static final String DATE_TYPE = "DATE";

    private class ComboBoxNode {
        private Object value;
        private String type;

        private ComboBoxNode(final Object value, final String type) {
            this.value = value;
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Objects.toString(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final ObservableList<ComboBoxNode> items =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new ComboBoxNode(LocalDate.now(), DATE_TYPE),
                        new ComboBoxNode("11:35AM", "TIME"));

        final PopOver datePopOver = new PopOver();
        datePopOver.setTitle("Enter new date");
        datePopOver.setCornerRadius(10);
        datePopOver.setHeaderAlwaysVisible(true);
        datePopOver.setCloseButtonEnabled(true);
        datePopOver.setAutoHide(true);

        final ComboBox<ComboBoxNode> customComboBox = new ComboBox<>(items);
        customComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, old, newNode) -> {
            if (newNode != null) {
                if (newNode.type.equals(DATE_TYPE)) {
                    final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker((LocalDate) newNode.value);
                    datePicker.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldDate, newDate) -> {
                        items.set(customComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedInde‌​x(), new ComboBoxNode(newDate, DATE_TYPE));
                        datePopOver.hide();
                    });

                    final StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(datePicker);
                    stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

                    datePopOver.setContentNode(stackPane);
                    datePopOver.show(customComboBox);
                } else {
                    datePopOver.hide();
                }
            }
        });

        final FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(customComboBox);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane.setPrefWidth(400);
        pane.setPrefHeight(300);

        // Show Scene
        final Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Popup calendar");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one more question I don't have methods like `datePopOver.setTitle("Enter new date");` and  `datePopOver.setCloseButtonEnabled(true);` do you have any idea why? The imports, classes are the same

Comment: I have another problem, when I select a date the `comboBox` doesn't updates the value chosen from datePicker. I think because my stringConver is not triggered after I pick a date. How can I do this?

Comment: @Dmytro Maslenko, could you update your answer to handle new dates being added to the `ComboBox`?  `items.set(customComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), new ComboBoxNode(newDate, DATE_TYPE));` should replace `items.set(0, new ComboBoxNode(newDate, DATE_TYPE));`.

Comment: @Sunflame, about missed methods. Make sure you have the latest library version in project dependencies. Try this workaround: titleProperty().set(title); and closeButtonEnabledProperty().setValue(true);

Comment: @Sunflame about not triggered updates. May you have the same date? In this case the trigger skips it. Otherwise provide your string converter.